# Timeout awaiting 'socket' for 60000ms with yarn install

Tags: yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I just upgraded yarn from 1.x.x to 3.2.1 (following applicable steps from https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration), but now when I run `yarn install` it fails every time with the following error:

```
YN0001: │ RequestError: Timeout awaiting 'socket' for 60000ms
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\[source].yarn\releases\yarn-3.2.1.cjs:195:14333)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at ClientRequest.o.emit (C:\Users\[source]\.yarn\releases\yarn-3.2.1.cjs:190:90453)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
[...abbreviated]
    at TLSSocket.emitRequestTimeout (node:_http_client:763:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 8m 30s
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 8m 30s
```

It does NOT print this in the same part of the output every time... and after the error, it continues to install dependencies as if nothing happens. But if I try `yarn start` afterwards, it errors due to packages missing in the lockfile, which I assume is due to the failed install.

I have already tried increasing the timeout interval, but it still errors with the same message (60000ms).

Any idea how I could figure out which package might be causing the issue, if any?

Comment: A change of internet connections solved the problem for me, but I still wish there were a way to determine what resource it was timing out on, or such. Perhaps this will be easier in the future once the [--verbose flag](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/763) is available!

Comment: It may be worth stating that I experience this error each time I try `yarn install` over a phone-tethered internet connection.